# How can I get standard offset of a timezone with momemnt

Tags: timezone, momentjs, timezone-offset

I need to find the offset of a specific timezone. How can I do that by using moment?

Lets say my client timezone is MST and I want to found the EST timezone offset. I need to get the standard offset without considering daylight saving.

With `moment.tz("America/Edmonton").format('Z')` I get `-6:00` but this considers daylight saving. I want something gives me `-7:00` as it is standard offset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this?

```js
function getStandardOffset(zone) {

  // start with now
  var m = moment.tz(zone);

  // advance until it is not DST
  while (m.isDST()) {
    m.add(1, 'month');
  }

  // return the formatted offset
  return m.format('Z');
}

getStandardOffset('America/Edmonton')  // returns "-07:00"
```

Of course, this returns the *current* standard offset.  If the time zone had used a different standard offset in the past, you'd need to start with a moment in that range, rather than "now".

Comment: Presumably it could also have issues with time zones in permanent DST?

Comment: Not with the current implementation of Moment.

Comment: In case of permanent DST timezone it will be an infinite loop, right?
So I changed it to:

Answer (score 1):

In case of permanent DST timezone it will be an infinite loop, right?
So what I ended up for my code is:

```
function getStandardOffset(zone) {

  // start with now
  var m = moment.tz(zone);

  // advance until it is not DST
  var counter = 1;
  while (m.isDST()) {
        m.add(1, 'month');
        if (counter > 12)
        {
            break;
        }
  }

  // return the formatted offset
  return m.format('Z');
}
```

Comment: Won't really matter with this data set, but sure - you can do that.  Also don't forget to increment the counter.